# Does perforce have $Id$ keyword?

Tags: perforce

We are using perforce in our project. I was wondering if there is a mechanism that could be used to embed an expandable keyword that is changed after each commit, like in `svn` and `git`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Perforce supports this for files that have the `+k` filetype set. See `p4 help filetypes` on how to set them. The supported RCS keywords are (straight from the [docs](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/appendix.filetypes.html#d0e15574)):

```
$Author$
$Change$
$Date$
$DateTime$
$File$
$Header$
$Id$
$Revision$
```